# Link to docker container cause TimeOut exception randomly

Tags: java, docker

Docker container which working fine in first 30 minute throw TimeoutException suddenly, what can be possible reasons for this condition.

I've restart the timeout container but it doesn't work, the only solution I've found is to restart the docker and restart containers.
Is there any better solution to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Give us some more information. What type of app is it? A webserver? What Framework are you using? Can this app "survive" more than 30 minutes if you run in outside Docker?

Comment: Sorry my bad, it is a springboot application, I run rabbitmq,mongo,redis and an eureka server in docker, the docker containers' survive time is not sure, it can be more than 30 minutes. And I find that all of  the docker containers will crash together. I tried Running rabbitmq,mongo,redis outside, they work fine. My platform is macOS High Sierra, docker version is 2.0.0.3 (31259).

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace from logs of those containers?

Comment: What's exactly crashing in the app? E.g. can u edit your question to include a stacktrace? Also, how are the containers crashing, do they just 'stop'? Have you checked the docker logs? May be related / useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311004/docker-services-stops-communicating-after-some-time

Comment: Finally I try running the same containers on windows10 and CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708, they are good running. So it probably is a bug of docker mac version. Thank you for all guys' helping.